# Meaning of the phrase Doy seguimiento?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, definiciones, expresiones, significado

If I emailed someone a question in Spanish about whether I should change something on a form or not, and they responded with "Doy seguimiento..." what does that mean?

Does it mean that "he will get back to me" ?

Comment: Can you attempt to guess? What would a direct translation would look like? Given the context, what could this person be trying to convey? Please note that we don't just translate on this site. We focus on learning, so it could be good if you tried first so then we can explain what you don't understand.

Comment: I understood it to mean he will get back to me?

Comment: I am Argentinian but my first language is English and this gentlemen is from Mexico so sometimes I don't really understand certain terms used

Comment: Could you give us more of the context?  I suspect it means "I am following up from your ...."

Answer (score 3):

As for your guess "to get back" it is correct but there is, I think, a closer expression to that in English.

> *Seguimiento* = Follow up.

So he means he will "follow up" this matter.

As I understand it "to follow up" is to  try to find out more about it or take action about it and then get back to you.

In Spanish "I'll get back to you" will be more like "*Te respondo después*" or "*Le daré una respuesta más tarde*" (I don't have time right now to reply) while "*Le daré seguimiento*" implies doing some actions before replying.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on: if you're asking for an answer in that moment, like in a call, "Doy seguimiento" is like "checking", if you're writing an email, then it is more like "I will follow up" or "I will check" and in that case, yes it is like "I'll get back to you".